# How to turn on the PDFTexify option?

Tags: compiling, winedt

I have read through the manual as best I can.  But I can't find where you enable or turn on the PDFTexify.  I put in some sample text.  Then I hit enter to try and "run" the text that I typed. So, then I read the manual again it said to hit "PDFTexify." Okay, I went to Tex and scrolled down to PDF. When I scrolled over to PDFTexify the  option is greyed out.

So, am I trying to read where it tells you how to "turn on" the PDFTexify option.  If you are patient enough please respond back with how to get that option to work.

Comment: Please specify more details about your environment and what program(s) you use...

Comment: I apologize, that I don't understand what you mean by environment. But I am using WindEdt to type up a math assignment. I did not know about WinEdt, LaTex, Miktek etc. I had been typing in the equations with MS Word Equation Editor.

Comment: So, I was told it would be much easier using Latex, Miktek, etc. So, I typed the equations in and I am supposed to use "PDFTexify" to convert the text.  However, when I go to click on "PDFTexify" its greyed out. All of the options are greyed out.  I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you typed?

Comment: Here is a sample I used from a help" manual:

Comment: @user29264 It seems something went wrong with your last comment, it ends after the dash. Please try again!

Comment: @user29264: You should put your code in a file with the extension `.tex`. Also make sure that you haven't make some other file without this extension to the "main file" (see menu project and the right of the status line on bottom).